# apt problems after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I'm not able to find and install GIMP via apt.

Here is the log:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
Reading package list...
Generating dependency tree...
Reading status information...
Some packages cannot be installed. This can mean
that an impossible situation has been requested or, if you are
using a distribution under development, that some required packages
they have not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libavcodec58 (>= 7:4.4)
                  Depends: libavformat58 (>= 7:4.4)
```

Comment: Try run the command like `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install gimp` so it will be English text.

Answer (score 0):

You have unmet dependencies, here what to do to fix that then install your package, open a terminal then run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

then install the missing dependencies `sudo apt install libavcodec58 libavformat58`

then you can try installing `gimp` again

```
sudo apt install gimp
```